# Missing Directory src/test/java after creation of maven project in IntelliJ

Tags: maven

IntelliJ:

JRE 1.8.0_152 – release – 915 – b6 amd64

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1 Build#IC-172.3544.35

I'm creating a maven project for selenium automation.

After creating new maven project and using the artifact type "quickstart" I don't see any directory `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`.

What could be the reason and how can I solve the issue? Thanks for any guides and support.

Create new Maven project using artifact type "quickstart":

[image]

After creation the/src/test/java Folder is missing:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should still be able to add `src/test/java` folder, and then right click on `src/test/java` and choose `Mark Directory As > Test Sources Root`.

Comment: Thanks for Hint. With Mark Directory As Test Source Root, I could get forward